# Enable quicks (double?) clicks on Ipad Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari, click

I'm building a HTML/JavaScript interface in which I would need some reactivity and so, the possibility for users to click really fast on the same button on the page.

I disabled the doubleclick/zoom on the iPad thanks to the `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />`, but then, if I double click or click too fast on the buttons, it does nothing.

I'm using jQuery and tried the dblclick event, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [doubletap plugin](https://github.com/technoweenie/jquery.doubletap) which enable the use of "doubletap" events on iPhone and iPad devices.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this, rolled my own inside my 'touchstart - move - touchend' sequence. Its horrible, but, inside my touchend, I have :

```
if (swipeMoving==0) {
swipeStarted = 0;
tapco +=1;
if (tapco==2) doDblClick();
window.setTimeout(function(){ tapco=0; }, 700);
return;
}
```

If you want click, too, put it in a delay, and cancel if the second click comes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to use double click in Ipad.
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/

Alternative :-

As click on the desktop browser is equivalent to the touch on the Ipad. So, the double click will be equivalent to the click on the Ipad.

To implement this :

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){
    $(".element").click(function () {/*run the code*/ });
}
else {
    $(".element").dblclick(function () {/*run the code*/ });
}
```

Hope it helps.